# Interaction between httpmodules and httphandlers

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

In our asp.net 2.0 app we are using httpmodule and httphandler to calculate some metrics via cookies. To calculate network transfer time, httpmodule:EndRequest stores Transferstart in the cookie and httphandler:Processrequest uses datetime.now to subtract the transferstart to determine overall network time. Is this correct? I am also unclear about the request flow process. Does it go something like this:
request > HttpModule::OnStart > HttpModule::OnEnd > HttpHandler::ProcessRequest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is:

- Module OnStart
- Handler ProcessRequest
- Module OnEnd

By the way, it's probably better to use `HttpContext.Items` property to share info between a handler and a module instead of a cookie.